# asp.net: Changing the value of the foreign key doesnt change the navigation value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Book model:

```
public class Book
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And a Transaction model that contains a reference to the Book model:

```
public class Transactions
{
    [Key]
    public int TransactionsId { get; set; }
    public DateTime BuyTime { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BookId")]
    public Book book { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that when i'm creating a new transaction and setting the BookId to '1' the book property stays null:

```
Transactioncs transaction = new Transactioncs();

// Init the book of the transaction
transaction.BookId = 1;
```

To my understanding, when I change the foreign key, the navigation property (in this case it's 'book') should change accordingly (as I have a book with id = 1 in my database).
Can someone please explain to me why the navigation property doesn't change?

Thanks

Comment: EntityFramework hydrate the ```Book``` property when you retrieve the object from the database. If you save your transaction instance, and then retrieves from database, EF will populate the book property.